# Why am I getting this Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level with writeFormula()?

Tags: php, pear

A maximum function nesting level is reached when I use the writeFormula() function.

Why am I getting this error? and How can it be solved?

Note that if I don't separate into functions and pass the `$workbook` as a parameter `by reference` to seperate functions calling `writeFormula()`,I do not get the error.

It seems to get into a loop:

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  152136  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.2733  3717224 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:26
3   0.2733  3717248 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.2737  3717472 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.5772  5224336 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.6058  5406400 Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:308
7   0.6062  5410664 ReportsController->excelAction( )   ..\Action.php:516
8   0.7471  9181488 Null_Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer->add_annual_worksheet( )  ..\ReportsController.php:42
9   4.1182  9851488 Null_Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer->add_trainingquantity( )  ..\Writer.php:403
10  4.1194  9852208 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Worksheet->writeFormula( ) ..\Writer.php:417
11  4.1196  9852712 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->parse( )   ..\Worksheet.php:1787
12  4.1207  9853200 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_condition( )  ..\Parser.php:1295
13  4.1207  9853536 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_expression( ) ..\Parser.php:1311
14  4.1207  9853736 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_term( )   ..\Parser.php:1391
15  4.1207  9853864 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_fact( )   ..\Parser.php:1440
16  4.1209  9854224 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_func( )   ..\Parser.php:1540
17  4.1235  9854536 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_condition( )  ..\Parser.php:1579
18  4.1235  9854536 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_expression( ) ..\Parser.php:1311
19  4.1235  9854536 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_term( )   ..\Parser.php:1391
20  4.1235  9854536 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_fact( )   ..\Parser.php:1440
21  4.1259  9854536 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_parenthesizedExpression( )    ..\Parser.php:1481
22  4.1259  9854616 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_expression( ) ..\Parser.php:1427
23  4.1259  9854616 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_term( )   ..\Parser.php:1391
24  4.1259  9854616 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_fact( )   ..\Parser.php:1440
25  4.1283  9854616 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_parenthesizedExpression( )    ..\Parser.php:1481
26  4.1283  9854672 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_expression( ) ..\Parser.php:1427
27  4.1284  9854672 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_term( )   ..\Parser.php:1391
28  4.1284  9854672 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_fact( )   ..\Parser.php:1440
29  4.1308  9854672 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_parenthesizedExpression( )    ..\Parser.php:1481
```

The below part is repeated till the max nesting level is reached:

```
30  4.1308  9854728 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_expression( ) ..\Parser.php:1427
31  4.1308  9854728 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_term( )   ..\Parser.php:1391
32  4.1308  9854728 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_fact( )   ..\Parser.php:1440
33  4.1332  9854728 Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Parser->_parenthesizedExpression( )    ..\Parser.php:1481
```

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is an xdebug setting. Modify your `php.ini` and increase [`xdebug.max_nesting_level`](http://xdebug.org/docs/basic).

34 is pretty low.

---

Try to increase it to 1024. If that does not work, report a bug with the exact code needed to reproduce the bug.